# How to report bug office execution arbitrary code to microsoft?

Tags: microsoft-office

I just discovered a bug concerned excel letting the execution of arbitrary code using a document of word. The question is how to report the bug and theres possible they patch it?

Comment: Visit www.Microsoft.com and find contact information for your region.

Answer (score 2):

Send an email to secure@microsoft.com.

The informationn you need to include is as follows (from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/msrc/faqs-report-an-issue?rtc=1)

```
Type of issue (buffer overflow, SQL injection, cross-site scripting, etc.)
Product and version that contains the bug, or URL if for an online service
Service packs, security updates, or other updates for the product you have installed
Any special configuration required to reproduce the issue
Step-by-step instructions to reproduce the issue on a fresh install
Proof-of-concept or exploit code
Impact of the issue, including how an attacker could exploit the issue
```